# after add content database, I can't see the document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Thanks, I had to reinstall my Sharepoint 3.0,  after creating Web Application, I attach or adding the content database ( the actual size is: 270Gb ), but then I can not see the any of my Document Library or documents, only one site ( empty ) .

I Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Check your content databases as it sounds like you still have the blank Content DB that a new web app is created with attached in addition to your restored DB.  A web App can only support 1 root site collection and it will ignore any additional ones.

Detach the blank content DB and restart IIS.  You should see your data again.

Comment: Yes, you have to point your new Web Application to your old content database...